# MySQL: Can I have multiple character sets for 1 column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table for translations. This table has a `locale` column, and a `name` column that could either be a string of english characters or chinese characters. Is it possible to have both UTF-8 and GBK (the character set for chinese characters) for one column / table? If so, how would I update my existing table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the collation to `utf_unicode_ci` worked:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this column varbinary and convert it on a client to every locale you want.